# Find the nearest Control

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I am Creating Controls dynamically in Screen. If i place a button in Screen then it should highlight and show the distance between closest Button which is located near to the newly placed Button.

Comment: Should it be a sibling (child of the same parent) or can it be any control?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Loop thru the visual tree of the entire view using `VisualTreeHelper` http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21495/Understanding-the-Visual-Tree-and-Logical-Tree-in ... here check the `TraverseVisualTree` method that you can use to go thru all elements in a visual tree.
2. For each `UIElement` control check its `ActualWidth` & `Actualheight` property.
3. Get the relative coordinate positions of the current UIElement. Using this code ... http://blogs.msdn.com/b/llobo/archive/2006/05/02/code-for-getting-screen-relative-position-in-wpf.aspx

Then using (relativePosition.X + actualWidth) and (relativePosition.Y + actualHeight) check for each element which one yields closest distance to the current element.